# Change dropdown selected text without changing the option text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an indented dropdownlist, where I have some root options and their children, like below:

```
Food
    Market
    Restaurants
    Grossery
Clothes
Home
    TV
```

If I select Market, for example, the text in the dropdownlist still indented. Then I did a jQuery function to remove the spaces before the text. It looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        var str = jQuery.trim($("select option:selected").text());

        $("select option:selected").text(str);
    })
});
```

It works. But, if I try to select other option after selected Market, for example, The list looks like this:

```
Food
Market
    Restaurants
    Grossery
Clothes
Home
    TV
```

Market lost its indentation. I would like a way to remove the spaces but only in the selected text shown in the dropdown, but not in the option.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you be a little more clear? What do you mean by "a way to remove the trim but only in the selected text shown in the dropdown, but not in the option"? Do you want to trim the text provided to the server when the form (containing the select) is submitted?

Comment: LOL, I mean a way to remove the SPACES. I'm an idiot, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit late to the party here...

First of all I've amended your HTML to include a class on each option element to indicate the level to which it should be indented.

```
<select class="select">
    <option value="1" class="level-0">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2" class="level-1">Item 1.1</option>
    <option value="3" class="level-2">Item 1.1.1</option>
    <option value="4" class="level-1">Item 1.2</option>
</select>
```

I have also written the jQuery to add the required indentation on load, using a string of non-breaking spaces. While this is hardly an elegant solution, it's the only one that will work across all browsers - as you've obviously discovered, OPTION elements are a land CSS forgot. It also includes the logic for the change event to remove/add the padding to the selected items.

While it's not the prettiest code, and I'm sure there are a lot of performance improvements which could be made (hey, it's late here and this was a brain dump as I was intrigued by the question), it works.

```
var levelClassPrefix = "level-";
var indentationString = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

$(".select").each(function() {
    padOptions(this);
});

function padOptions(elem) {
    $("OPTION", elem).each(function() {
        var level = $(this).attr("class").replace(levelClassPrefix, "");
        var currentText = $(this).html();
        var regex = new RegExp(indentationString , "g");
        $(this).html(padText(currentText.replace(regex, ""), level))
    });        
}

function padText(value, level) {
    var output = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= level; i++) {
        output = output + indentationString;
    }
    return output + value;
}

$(".select").change(function() {
    padOptions(this);

    var selectedOption = $("option:selected", this);
    var currentText = selectedOption .html();
    var regex = new RegExp(indentationString , "g");
    selectedOption.text(currentText.replace(regex, ""));
});
```

[Here is a fiddle to prove the theory](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwyjt/1/)

Comment: It kinda works. It indent, and they still indented after a change, but the actual selected item still lost its indentation. Thankz for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Why not style the indivudual options instead?

Something along these lines:

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>Food</option>
    <option class='sub'>Market</option>
    <option class='sub'>Restaurants</option>
    <option class='sub'>Grossery</option>
    <option>Clothes</option>
    <option>Home</option>
    <option class='sub'>TV</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
option.sub { text-indent: 2em; }
```

Comment: Same idea, better approach: +1, I will use text-indent as padding change the horizontal size of the container which is applied to

Answer (score 1):

Why trim the string? I would add a css class similar to this

```
select .level0 {}

select.level1 {
    text-indent: -1.5em; /* you have to calculate your indentation value */
}

select.level2 {
    text-indent: -3em; /* you have to calculate your indentation value */
}
```

Forge html accordingly

```
<select>
    <option class='level0'>Food</option>
    <option class='level1'>Market</option>
    <option class='level1'>Restaurants</option>
    <option class='level1'>Grossery</option>
    <option class='level0'>Clothes</option>
    <option class='level0'>Home</option>    
    <option class='level1'>TV</option>
</select>
```

and apply the class accordingly. Maybe, I don't know jquery, you have to

```
$(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        var theclass = $("select option:selected").class();
        $("select option:selected").set(class, theClass); // <-- is this jquery??
    })
});
```

Comment: I don't use CSS because neither of text-indent, padding or margin actually works in options here. It's valid? It should work? I can't get it to work!